# React-native tabbarIosItem

Tags: react-native

How do I allow tabbarIOS.item to use my image?

Here's my code

I have an image called itemSelected

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item
      selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'Item'}
      icon={require('image!itemNotSelected')}
      selectedIcon={require('image!itemSelected')}
      title="Item"
      onPress={() => {
          this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'Item',
          });
      }}>
```

However,  I can only see a square box being loaded from react-native in my tabbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A square box appears because your image has no transparent area, thus it filled up the entire image with blue resulting in a blue square box.

The code above works fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice [tutorial](http://devdactic.com/react-native-tab-bar/) for implementation of TabBar in React Native. You can use your image using:

```js
icon={{uri:'itemNotSelected'}}
selectedIcon={{uri:'itemSelected'}}
```

**Code from link:**

```js
render() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS selectedTab={this.state.selectedTab}>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'welcome'}
          icon={{uri:'featured'}}
          onPress={() => {
              this.setState({
                  selectedTab: 'welcome',
              });
          }}>
            <Welcome/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <TabBarIOS.Item
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'more'}
          icon={{uri:'contacts'}}
          onPress={() => {
                this.setState({
                    selectedTab: 'more',
                });
          }}>
          <More/>
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this doesn't work. it's still showing an empty square.

Comment: have you set your tab images in image assets?

Comment: yes, if not you will get the error of "the tab bar icon 'itemNotSelected' did not match any known image or system icon.